# React test checkbox doesn't checked on click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test my signup and i am using Formik and there is a checkbox in the form, but i dont know why my checkbox is not checked on click, could you help me please ?

there is my test

```
const fillAndSend = (component: RenderResult, email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string): void => {
  fireEvent.change(component.getByRole('textbox', { name: i18n.t('signUp:firstName') }), {
    target: { value: firstName }
  })

  fireEvent.change(component.getByRole('textbox', { name: i18n.t('signUp:lastName') }), {
    target: { value: lastName }
  })

  fireEvent.change(component.getByRole('textbox', { name: i18n.t('signUp:email') }), {
    target: { value: email }
  })

  fireEvent.change(component.getByRole('textbox', { name: i18n.t('signUp:password') }), {
    target: { value: password }
  })

  const checkbox = component.getByRole('checkbox')
  fireEvent.click(checkbox)

  const button = component.getByRole('button')
  fireEvent.click(button)
}

it('should sign up', async () => {

  const email = 'example@example.com'
  const password = '123456'
  const firstName = 'hello'
  const lastName = 'world'

  const component = render(<BrowserRouter><SignUp /></BrowserRouter>)

  act(() => {
    fillAndSend(component, email, password, firstName, lastName)
  })

  await waitFor(() =>
    expect(!!localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_ITEM_NAME)).toBe(true)
  )
})
```

but every time I `console.log` my checkbox, it's value is `false` ...

Comment: Could you please provide the code for the component you're testing?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check are you getting the checkbox correctly
for that you have to add a playground at the end of your test:

```
screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL()
```

then you can able to see and select the element, mostly playground will suggest how you can get the element
for more information check this:

> https://github.com/testing-library/testing-playground
> after getting the element correctly you can add await and act to make sure the checkbox will be checked at corect time like this

```
 await act(async () => {
   fireEvent.click(checkbox)
 })
```